# Calculating percentage in select query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have b/m query that calculates count and groups records on the basis of their status(SLABREACHED,WithInSLA).

```
select count(*) as Total,case when SLABREACHED=0 then 'WithInSLA' 
when SLABREACHED=1 then 'SLABREACHED' end as SLABREACHED
from mwp_main
where problemsince >= current timestamp - 7 days and problemsince < current timestamp
and status not in ('OPEN','REASSIGNED','REASSIGNED RESPONSE','REOPEN') 
group by slabreached
```

I need to calculate the total percentage of SLABREACHED and WithINSLA records along with their total count. I have been banging my head over this for a long time but cannot figure out out how to calculate percentage in the same above mentioned query.

Current query result is :

```
     Total                                   SLABREACHED

      68                                     WithInSLA

      10                                     SLABREACHED
```

I need :

Columns ::

```
       Total         Percentage              SLABREACHED

       68             80%                        WithInSLA

       10             20%                        SLABREACHED
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  Please provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cross join between you query and the query without group by

```
select count(*) as Total
  ,case when SLABREACHED=0 then 'WithInSLA' 
        when SLABREACHED=1 then 'SLABREACHED' end as SLABREACHED
  , (t.Total_general/count(*))*100 as perc 
from mwp_main 
CROSS  join  (
    select count(*) as Total_general
    from mwp_main
    where problemsince between  current timestamp - 7 days and p current timestamp
    and status not in ('OPEN','REASSIGNED','REASSIGNED RESPONSE','REOPEN') 
) t 
where problemsince between  current timestamp - 7 days and p current timestamp
and status not in ('OPEN','REASSIGNED','REASSIGNED RESPONSE','REOPEN') 
group by slabreached, total_general
```

Comment: Its not working. Query throwing the following error :
1) [Code: -119, SQL State: 42803]  An expression starting with "TOTAL" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.. SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, DRIVER=4.22.29

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what calculation you want -- the 80%/20% doesn't quite make sense.  However, if you want to divide by the total, then use window functions:

```
select (case when SLABREACHED = 0 then 'WithInSLA' 
             when SLABREACHED = 1 then 'SLABREACHED'
        end) as slabreached,
       count(*) as Total,
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ration
from mwp_main
where problemsince >= current timestamp - 7 days and
      problemsince < current timestamp and
      status not in ('OPEN', 'REASSIGNED', 'REASSIGNED RESPONSE', 'REOPEN') 
group by slabreached;
```

Answer (score 0):

See the description of the `ratio_to_report` olap function in [OLAP specification](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html).
Should be:

```
select 
  count(*) as Total
, int(ratio_to_report(count(*)) over() * 100) || '%' as Percentage
, case when SLABREACHED=0 then 'WithInSLA'
  when SLABREACHED=1 then 'SLABREACHED' end as SLABREACHED
from mwp_main
where problemsince >= current timestamp - 7 days and problemsince < current timestamp
and status not in ('OPEN','REASSIGNED','REASSIGNED RESPONSE','REOPEN') 
group by slabreached;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your query worked. Is there a way to use Alias in concat functions . Actually I want show my result with SLABREACHED and its percentage in same cell divided by a "/" , I have tried using concat but cannot use alias in concat function .

Comment: See the updated answer. If it's not the solution you need, then provide exact desired output needed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain my question correctly.
I require the data in following format 
Percentage/Total 
If Percent SLABreached is 78 and Total SLABRECHED is 100 then I need the result like 78/100

Comment: Updated answer returns the result as you specified in the question exactly. BTW, I don't understand how `Total SLABRECHED` (total percentage?) can be not equal to 100...